# Good papers with reproducible analysis requiring only the basics

Tags: self-study, references

I'm looking for papers or other examples of research where the statistical analysis done would be within the grasp of someone who has done an introductory stats course. Ideally the datasets would also be available online.

The idea is to pass these to students and examples they can follow and reproduce.

Comment: There are thousands of scientific papers that use nothing more than ANOVA and t-tests. Some of them even correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the Universit of Goettingen they started a Wiki collecting various studies and their replications: http://replication.uni-goettingen.de/